# Recurring events that only occur on business days

Tags: calendar, recurring-events

I've got a user who is creating recurring events for report reminders for the first day of the month. However these days sometimes fall on a Saturday or Sunday.

How do I get Sharepoint to default this to the first WORKING day of the month (ie mon-fri)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint allows you to set up a monthly recurrence pattern for the first "weekday" of a month.  I believe this is what you want.

Comment: Cheers. I only saw that now... "doh!"

Answer (score 0):

[supplebee.com](https://supplebee.com) allows you to create events on nth business day of the month and export the calendar as an ICS file. In addition to avoiding weekends, it can even avoid public holidays of your country/region.